# Count pattern instances using grep

Tags: command-line, grep

I'm trying to count `/` in a certain path, but `grep` counts all instances as 1 when it is in 1 line.

```
/home/usr/bin/test | grep / -c
```

gives an answer `1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your command would actually count the number of *lines* containing `/` in the *standard output* of *command* `/home/usr/bin/test`

Here are some options to count the instances of `/` in the *string* `/home/usr/bin/test`:

```
grep -o '/' <<< "/home/usr/bin/test" | wc -l

tr -dc '/' <<< "/home/usr/bin/test" | wc -c
```

Answer (score 4):

As `grep -c` counts number of lines that contain the pattern. Using the `-o` option outputs matched content on different lines. You can then use `-c` to count those lines.

```
grep -o '/' <<< "/home/usr/bin/test" |  grep '/' -c
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk` (Print each line separately):

```
awk -F"/" '{print NF-1}' my.txt
```

- `-F"/"`: consider `/` as field delimiters
- `NF-1`: number of fields-1.

Print all lines:

```
tr -d '\n' < my.txt | awk -F"/" '{print NF-1}'
```

---

Using `sed` and `grep`:

```
sed "s@/@/\n@g" my.txt | grep -c /
```

- `sed "s@/@/\n@g"` puts a new line after each `/` so `grep` can count all of them.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong because:

- `-c` flag counts number of matching lines
- `"/home/usr/bin/test | grep / -c` is literally means that you're trying to execute `/home/usr/bin/test` file and pipe its output to `grep`

What you should be doing is this:

- count individual output of `grep` with

  ```
  grep -o '/'  <<< "/home/usr/bin/test" | wc -l
  ```
- use  tools other than `grep`:

  ```
   # saving matches to array and printing array in scalar context
   $ perl -ne '@arr = $_ =~ /\//g;print 0+@arr' <<< "/home/usr/bin/test"                                                    
   4

   #  building list of only / chars and getting length of that list
   $ python -c 'import sys; print(len([char for line in sys.stdin for char in line if char == "/"]))' <<< "/home/usr/bin/test"
   4

   # iterating over each character of string using substr
   $ awk '{for(i=1;i<=length($0);i++) if(substr($0,i,1)=="/") count++}END{print count}' <<< "/home/usr/bin/test"            
   4
  ```